# Error while creating own library in Robot framework + SSHLIbrary

Tags: robotframework

I am executing the case from windows machine to linux server.

I have created my own library in which i have defined Clearlog method and using it as a keyword in Robot.

**Problem:  After opening the connection code in Clearlog is getting executed on windows machine itself instead of linux machine, after opening a connection i want to continue the session of linux and execute the code of Clearlog in linux machine.**

please find below code :

```
*** Settings ***
Variables         ../../Desktop/robot/Python_Programs/Squid_Details.py
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Squid_proxy_Verification
    Open Squid Connection
    Clearlog

*** Keywords ***
Open Squid Connection
    ${SwitchToSquid}=    Open Connection    ${Squid_IP}
    Login    ${Squid_Username}    ${Squid_Password}
```

Comment: where is the keyword Clearlog defined?

Comment: it is on path '../../../../Python27/Lib/site-packages/SSHLibrary/clearlog.py' of windows machine.
PS: i am able to use the keyword but it's getting executed on Windows machine instead of Linux machine.

Comment: ahh! to run on remotemachine you have to use ExecuteCommand here in robot code..